# select between two dates

Tags: java, sql

I have a database whose one table (query_user) has 4 columns out of which 2 (access_time, answer_time) are of timestamp (e.g. 2011-08-11 01:18:41.712) type.
I want to query on that table, such as follows:

```
String query="select access_time from query_user where access_time between ? and ?";
```

Now in my java code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
Connection con = DBConnectionManager.getConnection();
ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

ps.setString(1,"2011-08-11 01:18:41.712");
ps.setString(2,"2011-09-11 01:18:41.712");
```

I'm not sure about what should I use at `ps.setDate()` or `ps.setString()` or `ps.setInt()`?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

use `ps.setDate()` as the database column is datetime

Comment: And pass it a `java.sql.Date` object ;)

Comment: But only if you don't need the time part. Otherwise use  `setTimestamp()` and `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: He said it's timestamp value, shouldn't it be `ps.setTimestamp`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ps.setString()` method in database that string treated as `DateTime` or `timestamp` type.dont worry..